# getting sum of grouped data angularjs - angular-filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

i am using angular-filter to group data. while i was able to group data and get data length(`orderfood`), i am not able to get sum of the `qty` in my grouped data. my [plunk demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/OmQfBEnIRTPw3DIW8tFx?p=preview)

the result i got

```
Isnain Meals - 2

Chicken Burger - 2
```

the result i need

```
Isnain Meals - 4 //sum of qty of Isnain Meals from JSON data (1+3)

Chicken Burger - 9 //sum of qty of Chicken Burger from JSON data (3+6)
```

**JSON Data**

```
$scope.orders = [{
  "_id": "56b0c315e179bb0e00a44dbf",
  "orderfood": [{
    "_id": "569d865bff1fe20e00f8ba97",
    "qty": "1",
    "confirm": true,
    "price": 154,
    "name": "Isnain Meals"
  }, {
    "_id": "569d865bff1fe20e00f8ba98",
    "qty": "3",
    "confirm": true,
    "price": 154,
    "name": "Isnain Meals"
  }],
  "content": "9176649143",
  "created": "2016-02-02T14:54:13.926Z"
}, {
  "_id": "56b06ed25b53250e00ccbd73",
  "orderfood": [{
    "_id": "569d84f04834c10e003dff36",
    "qty": "6",
    "confirm": true,
    "price": 125,
    "name": "Chicken Burger"
  }],
  "content": "6886058585",
  "created": "2016-02-02T08:54:42.986Z"
}, {
  "_id": "56b06ed25b53250e00ccbd74",
  "orderfood": [{
    "_id": "569d84f04834c10e003dff37",
    "qty": "3",
    "confirm": true,
    "price": 125,
    "name": "Chicken Burger"
  }],
  "content": "6886058585",
  "created": "2016-02-02T08:54:42.986Z"
}];
```

**Controller Code**

```
$scope.getOrderFoods = function() {
var orderfood = [];

angular.forEach($scope.orders, function(order) {
  angular.forEach(order.orderfood, function(orderfoo) {
    if (orderfood.indexOf(orderfoo) == -1) {
      orderfood.push(orderfoo);
    }
  })
});
return orderfood;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,data) in getOrderFoods() | groupBy:'name'">
  <p>{{key}} - {{data.length}}</p>
<!-- instead of the data.length, i need the sum of qty   -->
</div>
```

my [plunk demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/OmQfBEnIRTPw3DIW8tFx?p=preview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use javascript Array.reduce method to generate the sum of quantity. here is the [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/flWYHM1bSYqSbA1BmMec?p=preview)

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,data) in getOrderFoods() | groupBy:'name'">
      <p>{{key}} - {{reduce(data)}}</p>
</div>


$scope.reduce= function(data){
   return data.reduce(function(previousValue,currentValue, currentIndex, array){
     return previousValue + parseInt(currentValue.qty);
  }, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your solution used `data.length` that return array length not total `qty` because of `groupBy` generate an array based on groupBy conditioncan.

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,data) in getOrderFoods() | groupBy:'name'">
  <p>{{key}} - {{data.length}}</p>
</div>
```

in this repeat generate two array with two items in each array because of you have two type item name and each type two times.

You can use another function to calculate total quantity that will call from in `ng-repeat`. In my solution used `getTotalQuantity(data)`

likeIn html:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,data) in getOrderFoods() | groupBy:'name'">
   <p>{{key}} - {{getTotalQuantity(data)}}</p>
</div>
```

in controller:

```
$scope.getTotalQuantity = function(items) {
    var total =0;
    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
       total+= parseInt(item.qty);
    });
    return total;
}
```