# AngularJS: Order by sum of grouped list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

I have a list of single match outcomes of different teams in the following form:

```
    [{team: "A", w: 1, l: 0, t: 0, date: '2018-10-01'},
     {team: "B", w: 1, l: 0, t: 0, date: '2018-10-01'},
     {team: "C", w: 0, l: 1, t: 0, date: '2018-10-01'},
     {team: "D", w: 0, l: 1, t: 0, date: '2018-10-01'},
     {team: "A", w: 1, l: 0, t: 0, date: '2018-10-08'},
     {team: "B", w: 0, l: 1, t: 0, date: '2018-10-08'},
     {team: "C", w: 0, l: 0, t: 1, date: '2018-10-08'},
     {team: "D", w: 0, l: 0, t: 1, date: '2018-10-08'},
     {team: "A", w: 1, l: 0, t: 0, date: '2018-10-15'},
     {team: "D", w: 0, l: 0, t: 0, date: '2018-10-15'},
     {team: "B", w: 1, l: 0, t: 0, date: '2018-10-15'},
     {team: "B", w: 1, l: 0, t: 0, date: '2018-10-17'},
     {team: "B", w: 1, l: 0, t: 0, date: '2018-10-20'},
     {team: "C", w: 0, l: 1, t: 0, date: '2018-10-20'},
     {team: "C", w: 0, l: 1, t: 0, date: '2018-10-22'}]
```

Using `ng-repeat` and `angular.filter` I am now able to display that data in a table grouped by team. Using [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36156554) I am also able to aggregate the game outcomes to produce a record for each team:

```
Rank    Team    Games   Wins    Losses  Ties
1       A       3       3       0       0
2       D       3       0       1       1
3       C       4       0       3       1
4       B       5       4       1       0
```

[Here is a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g4b5tcqp/) of what I got so far.

Additionally I have a [datepicker](https://github.com/indrimuska/angular-moment-picker) placed in the view from which the user will be able to select date ranges. Upon changing these dates the aggregates are updated. This is also already working.

My problem now is that I am unable to order my table by any of the displayed categories. I tried different things like using any kind of `orderBy:` clause imaginable. I also tried putting the result of my aggregation in a variable (like `{{ wins = reduce(group, 'w') }}`) to be referenced in the `orderBy:`, but to no avail.

Is it at all possible what I'd like to achieve?

Comment: There's a number of outdated practices here that I feel make it more difficult for you. You should be initiating the data within the controller so you don't have to rely on the piped directives, and then sorting by clicking a column header is just as easy: simply sort the array by the wins, or losses, or what have you.

Comment: Agree. Map/reduce the data first before sending to view

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This is a scaled down version of what I‘m actually doing, maybe that’s a reason why it seems a little awkward. What do you mean by *initiating the data within the controller*?

Comment: I updated the fiddle to show you. It's not complete, but basically all you need to do is calculate the ranks and put that on it's own property, maybe 'r'

https://jsfiddle.net/g4b5tcqp/1/

Comment: Thanks again, I'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to take advantage of the fact you can pass a function as the expression argument into `orderBy`. Inside this function you can compute the summation of all items in a group for each property, then use the result as the value to order by.

The adjustment to your HTML:

```
ng-repeat="group in data | groupBy: 'team' | toArray:true | orderBy:category"
```

And the relevant JS to make it happen:

```
// $scope.order is a user option to specify the property to order by
$scope.category = function (value) {
    // The games column is not a data item property so it is treated specially
    if ($scope.order === 'games') {
        return value.length;
    }
    return value.reduce(function (total, dataItem) {
        return total + dataItem[$scope.order];
    }, 0);
};
```

[And here's forked JSFiddle demonstrating the suggestion.](https://jsfiddle.net/0nktaqsb/)